# Add node(s), new rack

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a 16 node Cassandra 2.1.11 Cluster, divided into 2 racks (R0 and R1), 8 nodes per rack. Each node serves about 700Gb of data. The cluster looks pretty balanced. Each node has 2x3Tb HDD.

```
Datacenter: DC0
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.21.72  677.37 GB  256     ?       0260665f-5f5c-4fbc-9583-8da86848713a  R0
UN  192.168.21.73  658.8 GB   256     ?       ed1e7814-f715-41c8-97c9-8b52164835f9  R1
UN  192.168.21.74  676.97 GB  256     ?       62833182-b339-46f2-9370-0e23f6bb7eab  R1
UN  192.168.21.75  657.1 GB   256     ?       ab31f28b-ffea-489f-a4da-3b5120760b8e  R1
UN  192.168.21.76  690.29 GB  256     ?       e636bf2e-89d6-4bf3-9263-cf1ed67fcbd9  R1
UN  192.168.21.77  679.77 GB  256     ?       959e5207-1251-4c58-afa9-3910b5a27ff5  R1
UN  192.168.21.78  648.85 GB  256     ?       6f650315-1cd1-4169-b300-391800be974f  R1
UN  192.168.21.79  675.96 GB  256     ?       324bd475-b5f6-4b39-a753-0cd2c80a46c4  R1
UN  192.168.21.65  636.01 GB  256     ?       65e3faa1-e8d5-4d78-a87e-bfde1f4095a5  R0
UN  192.168.21.66  674.89 GB  256     ?       213696eb-c4a0-4803-a9b3-0efd04c567f2  R0
UN  192.168.21.67  716.77 GB  256     ?       62542a8e-8177-4f13-9077-ea2426607ace  R0
UN  192.168.21.68  666.1 GB   256     ?       a9864059-3de2-48a2-a926-00db3f9791ee  R0
UN  192.168.21.69  691.9 GB   256     ?       02ea1b28-90f9-4837-8173-ff79fa6966d7  R0
UN  192.168.21.70  681.16 GB  256     ?       a9c8adae-e54e-4e8e-a333-eb9b2b52bfed  R0
UN  192.168.21.71  653.18 GB  256     ?       6aa8cf0c-069a-4049-824a-8359d1c58e59  R0
UN  192.168.21.80  694.14 GB  256     ?       7abb5609-7dca-465a-a68c-972e54469ad6  R1
```

Now I'm trying to expand the cluster by adding 16 more nodes, also divided into 2 racks (R2 and R3). After adding all new nodes I expect a 32 node cluster, divided by 4 racks, with 350Gb of data on each node.

I add one node at a time according to the [Cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html). I started Cassandra process at the first node, with the same configuration as existing nodes, but in R3 (new) rack. It caused 16 streams from existing nodes to newly added node, 250Gb of data in each, all data successfully transferred to new node, at this point process looks normal.

But after that data size lands on the new node, as shown by `nodetool status` it's starting to increase, now it already says 1.7Tb and keeps growing.

```
UJ  192.168.21.89  1.69 TB    256     ?       42a80db9-59d6-44b6-b79c-ac7819f69cee  R3
```

It's something opposite to what I expected (350Gb per node but not 1.7Tb).
4Tb disk space out of 6Tb already used by Cassandra data dir on the new node.

I've thought that it isn't normal and have stopped the process.

Now I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and what I should do to add 16 nodes properly and have 32 nodes with 350Gb on each node in the end. Should I expand existing racks instead of adding new ones? Should I calculate tokens for new nodes? Any other options?

Comment: Not sure why you didn't get an answer on this, did you still need help on this? Often large data sizes are caused by "overstreaming" which is when you bootstrap, and stop for whatever reason and then bootstrap again. It doesnt start from where it left off, so your data load might be due to re-trying bootstraps?